# Constructor of Singleton running when changing form

Tags: c#, winforms, singleton

I'm creating a small piece of software.
I have three forms that gives me a headache. Two of these forms are Singletons.

The form not being a Singleton is a login form which is only suppose to be shown when the application start. Then I have a mainform which is shown when the correct username and password is entered in the login form. This works.

Then from a menustrip, you can switch to another form containing a list of users and some information about these. On that form I have a button that takes you back to the mainform. When I press that button, instead of taking me back to the mainform directly, I'm presented with the login form again.

Code triggered from the menustrip item clicked, to take you from the mainform to the userform:

```
private void miBrugere_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        userForm = Userform.Instance;
        this.Hide();
        userForm.Show();
    }
```

Code that it supposed to take you from the userform and back to the mainform:

```
private void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Mainform mainForm = Mainform.Instance;
        this.Hide();
        mainForm.Show();
    }
```

Code that runs on the load of my mainform:

```
private void Mainform_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (firstLoad)
        {
            firstLoad = false;
            Loginform loginForm = new Loginform();
            this.Hide();
            loginForm.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

The firstLoad variable is classwide.

Thanks in advance :-)

I've boiled it down to when I create an instance on my userform for the first time I run this code:

```
public Userform()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dgvUsers.AllowUserToAddRows = false;

        Mainform mainForm = Mainform.Instance;
        connString = mainForm.connString;

        --Awesome stuff--
    }
```

And apparently, when calling the Mainform.instance, the instance is null and thereby it creates a new instance of mainform instead of retrieving the one already used. And of course, this means that since firstLoad is a classwide variable, this will be set to true again.

Comment: How is `Mainform.Instance` implemented?

Comment: @DominicKexel public static Mainform Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new Mainform();
                }
                return instance;
            }
        }

Comment: Are you assigning _firstLoad = true_ in your code? Where?

Comment: @BitExodus public partial class Mainform : Form
    {
        private static Mainform instance;
        Userform userForm;
        Boolean locked = true;
        Boolean firstLoad = true;
        public string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WindowsAuth"].ConnectionString; }

Comment: How does your main entry point for the application (usually the `Main` method in `Program.cs` for newly created windows forms applications) look like? If it's something like `Application.Run(new Mainform());`, then your `Mainform` isn't a singleton. You might want to try `Application.Run(Mainform.Instance)`.

Comment: @Corak You're the man! I had totally forgotten that class even existed, since it's only purpose has been to run my Mainform, eveything works now!

Comment: You should declare your _Mainform_ constructors as private if you are implementing a singleton ;).

Comment: @BitExodus That would of course have led me to the problem too. But I rarely ever use Singletons, so I always forget something :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How does your main entry point for the application (usually the Main
>   method in Program.cs for newly created windows forms applications)
>   look like? If it's something like Application.Run(new Mainform());,
>   then your Mainform isn't a singleton. You might want to try
>   Application.Run(Mainform.Instance)

The answer came from Corak, so props to him!

Comment: Glad I could help ^_^. The main point is `"your Mainform isn't a singleton"`. As @BitExodus pointed out, the constructors need to be private in order for it to be a "real" singleton.